# How to use python-slackclient RTM using multiple token (bot-user)

Tags: python, slack-api

Hi I have an issue integrating slack custom bot-user into my slack app, based on python-slackclient documentation [python-slackclient](https://github.com/slackhq/python-slackclient)

to use the RTM

```
import time
from slackclient import SlackClient

token = "xoxp-xxxxxxxxx"# found at https://api.slack.com/web#authentication
sc = SlackClient(token)
if sc.rtm_connect():
    while True:
         print sc.rtm_read()
         time.sleep(1)
else:
    print "Connection Failed, invalid token?"
```

that code is working for bot-user token, but since I use oauth, I need to connect RTM using the `bot_access_token` everytime user install my app to act on behalf my app to the added team

any solution or example how to do it?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Your question is had to understand. You wrote:

> since I use oauth, I need to connect RTM using the bot_access_token everytime user install my app to act on behalf my app to the added team

The access token you're using here...

```
token = "xoxp-xxxxxxxxx"# found at https://api.slack.com/web#authentication
```

...should be the same as the access token that is associated with your bot. (You should *not* make your bot use your own personal access token!) You can get an access token for your bot at https://my.slack.com/services/new/bot (assuming you're logged into Slack in the browser with which you follow that link).

If you participate in multiple Slack "teams" (a Slack "team" being basically a company), you'll need to set up a separate bot for each "team". Each bot will have a different access token. To pass the correct access token in to your bot, you could add a command-line parameter, or read the token from an environment variable, or read it from disk, among other options.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over tokens for connecting if you are planning to setup bot
 for multiple teams, then your code can be converted to :-

```
clients = [SlackClient(token) for t in tokens]
for client in clients:
    client.rtm_connect()
while True:
    for client in clients:
        print client.rtm_read()
        time.sleep(1)
```